# std::atomic<T*> refCount in own implementation of shared ptr

Tags: c++

According to the assignment, it is necessary to make `refCount` not `size_t`, but `std::atomic`. Initially it was like this:

```
namespace smartptr {
template <typename T> class sharedPtr {

    private:
      T *ptr = nullptr;
      size_t *refCount = nullptr;
    
    public:
      sharedPtr() = default;
    
      explicit sharedPtr(T *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_), refCount(new size_t(1)) {}
    
      sharedPtr(const sharedPtr &obj) : ptr(obj.ptr), refCount(obj.refCount) {
        if (nullptr != obj.refCount)
          *refCount = *refCount + 1;
      }
    
      sharedPtr(sharedPtr &&obj) noexcept : ptr(obj.ptr), refCount(obj.refCount) {
        obj.ptr = nullptr;
        obj.refCount = nullptr;
      }
.....
```

How to correctly apply the operations of adding, deleting, creating `refCount`, taking into account the fact that the type is atomic? For example, in the first constructor I tried to do this:

```
explicit sharedPtr(T *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_), refCount.store(1) {}
```

But an error comes up:

> no matching member function for call to 'store'

Comment: "not size_t, but std::atomic"? how about `std::atomic<size_t>`?

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer and make sure you've created the atomic first: `explicit sharedPtr(T *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_), refCount(new std::atomic<size_t>(1)){}`

Comment: Modifications of the counter need to be replaced with the atomic vesions btw: `*refCount = *refCount + 1;` should become `refCount->fetch_add(1);` (real code should specify the memory order of the operation of course)

Comment: If I write explicit sharedPtr(T *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_), refCount(new std::atomic<size_t>(1)){}, get an error "no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::atomic<size_t *>' (aka 'atomic<unsigned long *>')". std::atomic<size_t>* refCount or std::atomic<size_t*> refCount; (i think the first)

Comment: @fabian given the question, OP is better off not specifying anything non-default.

Comment: @OP the error is pretty clear. You have `std::atomic<size_t *>` as your member, change it to `std::atomic<size_t>*`. Or initialize it with `size_t*`.

Comment: And why can't I use the store operation? For example sharedPtr(const sharedPtr &obj) : ptr(obj.ptr), refCount.store(obj.refCount) {

Comment: @ixSci, I have to create a pointer to a reference count, not just a reference count

Comment: Then it should be `refCount{new size_t(1)}`